# What are good codecs for Animated screen captures? Are there any good open-source solutions?

Tags: video, codec

Most video codecs are optimized for movies. However, not all videos look like real-world movies, and usual codecs do not aways give good results.

So are there methods specifically designed for cartoons/animated screen captures? Are there any open-source implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i once saw a 2h cartoon movie (manga) encoded with theora, which they somehow got down to ~150MB and still extremely crisp - even in fullscreen (dion't ask me how they did, but that must have taken a load of tweaking)

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the [Tech Smith Codec](http://www.techsmith.com/codecs/tscc/default.asp) as used in Camtasia and Snagit) would be a good choice.

[Cam Studio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/camstudio/) appears to be open source - I assume their codec is also.